# Load from database into WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to load content (from my database) into a page from different years.

```
$yearQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(startDate) AS year FROM series ORDER BY startDate DESC");

if(mysql_num_rows($yearQuery) > 0) {
    while($year = mysql_fetch_assoc($yearQuery)) {
        echo "<li><a href='/teaching/podcasts?year=".$year['year']."'>".$year['year']."</a></li>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<li>".mysql_error()."</li>";
}
```

I have managed to get this one to work sucessfully:

```
while($yearSeries = mysql_fetch_assoc($yearSeriesQ)) {
    echo "<div class='prevSermon'>";
        echo "<div class='prevImage'>";
            echo "<a href='/teaching/podcasts?id=".$yearSeries['id']."'><img height='90' width='90' alt='".$yearSeries['title']."' src='/admin/".$yearSeries['image']."'/></a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo $yearSeries['title'];
    echo "</div>";
}
```

which shows the weeks in a previous series.

What am I doing wrong with the years, one which is the archive in the [bottom right hand side](http://dev.thrivinglifechurch.org/teaching/podcasts/)?

Comment: The current Archive link isn't being generated by the first piece of code - it's generating a link to `podcasts/id=`.

Comment: Yes, as @andrewsi points out, the HTML code you're linking does not match the PHP you're showing. Better that you paste it here than linking to a site that tomorrow will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress you don't have to do raw SQL queries like you are doing here. There are several ways to get posts that are much more secure. You should try using [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and pass exactly the arguments you need to get your posts. This will also return the posts as an object which you can run [`setup_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) on and use the Wordpress magic functions like [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content).

Using this method, you should be able to target the exact posts you need. Just compare them to the arguments in the Codex that pertain to your specific case. Note, you can also do meta queries and joins just like you can in raw SQL.

Comment: Looks like the OP is dealing with custom tables, in which case this would be the relevant documentation: [Class_Reference/wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).